# multi-word search in solr (sunspot) for returning closest match

Tags: solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using sunspot to search my rails app, but I'm not getting the results I'm hoping for.

I've got the index built on my 'classes' models name field, so I have for example

```
Engineering
Electrical Engineering
Mechanical Engineering
Fluid Dynamics
```

If a user searches `fluid engineering`, I suspected that sunspot would give me back all the results of fluid and engineering and let me figure out what I wanted from there. But unfortunately I'm getting back an empty result set.

I pose my query to Solr like this

```
classes = Sunspot.search Class do |query|
            query.keywords params[:search]
        end.results
        return render :json=> classes
```

I tried to join my params[:search] with `+`, wrapping it in `{}` and `()`, but I haven't got the results i'm looking for. I think the problem is in how the query is being posted rather than the solr settings in the xml file, but I'm not entirely positive.

My analyzer is

```
 <analyzer>
         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
         <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
       </analyzer>
```